# Get purchase date from Google Play Store and Apple App Store

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xamarin

I need your help with the following topic: We have developed an app with Xamarin forms for Android and iOS. The user has to pay for it. Depense on the purchase date we have to do something in the app.

When the app is installed we can save the first installation date within the app. But, if the user reinstall the app on a new device, the output starts from the beginning. So I think we need to request the purchase date from the app store (google and Apple).

I googled for it but have no clear answer how to do it.
Is there somebody who can help with this?
How can I request the purchase date of the app?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The user pays for the entire app? As in, you charge for downloading your app from the respective store or are you referencing in-app purchases?

Answer (score 0):

For Apple, it's easy.  Simply use Receipt Validation.

Documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Sample Code:

```
-(void)getReceipt //check if local recipt exists.  if not, get one
{
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    NSError* err = nil;
    if (![receiptURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]){ //if no local receipt
        SKReceiptRefreshRequest* request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
   }
    else
        [self getReceipt2:receipt];

}


-(void)getReceipt2:(NSData *)receipt //check recipt with apple and parse it.
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                      @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
                                      };
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];

    if (!requestData) { NSLog(@"RequestData Error");}

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; //https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt for sandbox
    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
    [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if (connectionError) {
                                   NSLog(@"Connection Error");
                               } else {
                                   NSError *error;
                                   NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                                   if (!jsonResponse) { NSLog(@"Json Error"); return;}
                                   NSArray *results = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"receipt"];
                                   NSString *strPurchaseDate = [results valueForKey:@"original_purchase_date"];
                                   }

}
```

For Android, I haven't yet found a way... :(

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a Xamarin.forms solution.